# how to split Associative array into keys and values separately

Tags: php

```html
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
print_r($data);
parse_str($data, $result);
print_r($result);
```

how to split this associative array as keys and values in separate array

Answer (score 1):

use `array_keys()` and `array_values()`

```
$json   = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data   = json_decode($json);
$keys   = array_keys($data);
$values = array_values($data);
print_r($keys);
print_r($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
[array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
$res_key[] = $key;
$res_val[] = $value;
}

print_r($res_key);
print_r($res_val);
```